# Partial instantiation of template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Suppose I build a class template with template parameter:

```
template<template<typename> class A> class B;
```

And now I want to make an instantiation, for example for `A` being functions taking int (e.g. for arguments like `template<class T> void f(int)`). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you ask if a *function template* can be a templates *template parameter*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [Template template arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments) can't be used with function template.

> A template argument for a template template parameter must be an
>   id-expression which names a class template or a template alias.

Answer (score 1):

As per the other answer, template template arguments cannot be used with function templates. You could however, simulate desired functionality by wrapping your function in a templated functor instead. The simplest would be an `std::function`. Here is a silly example to demonstrate this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<template <class A> class T>
class B
{
public:    
    template<typename Arg>
    void invoke(T<Arg> target, Arg arg)
    {
        target(arg);
    }
};

template<typename T>
void f(T arg)
{
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
using fWrapper = std::function<void(T)>;

int main()
{
    B<fWrapper> b;

    b.invoke<int>(fWrapper<int>(f<int>), 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass template functions around to other templates.

You can create template objects that *act* like template functions, such as:

```
struct my_wrapper {
  template<class T>
  static void invoke(int) {};
};
```

You can pass a type and expect that it have a static template function called `invoke` that takes a type.